# String formatting: better to use '%' or 'format'?

Tags: python, string

I use python 3.4 and I can format strings in two ways:

```
print("%d %d" %(1, 2))
```

and

```
print("{:d} {:d}".format(1, 2))
```

In [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) they show examples only using 'format'. Do it mean that using '%' is not good, or it does not matter which version to use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quoting from the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format),

> This method of string formatting is the new standard in Python 3, and should be preferred to the % formatting described in String Formatting Operations in new code.

So, `format` is the recommended way to do, going forward.

Comment: that said % formatting has no plans of going obsolete... and I prefer it most of the time(not that my personal preference justifies its use for anyone other than myself) ...

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the recommendations on the official site the format() method is more flexible, powerful and readable than operator '%'.

For example:

```
>>> '{2}, {1}, {0}'.format(*'abc')
'c, b, a'
>>> coord = {'latitude': '37.24N', 'longitude': '-115.81W'}
>>> 'Coordinates: {latitude}, {longitude}'.format(**coord)
'Coordinates: 37.24N, -115.81W'
>>> "Units destroyed: {players[0]}".format(players = [1, 2, 3])
'Units destroyed: 1'
```

and more, and more, and more... Hard to do something similar with the operator '%'.